# Determinant of a linear transformation $T.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be the real vector space of $2\times 3$ matrices with real entries. Let $T:M \rightarrow M$ be defined by  $$T(\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3}  \\
    x_{4} & x_{5} & x_{6}  \\
\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{6} & x_{4} & x_{1}  \\
    x_{3} & x_{5} & x_{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ Then the determinant of $T$ is

$A. 1.$

$B. 2.$

$C.-1.$

$D.0.$

Now one method is as usual  firstly find the matrix of the transformation $T$ with respect to usual basis of $W$ and then find the determinant of the matrix thus obtained which come as $-1.$ But i want some short trick that gives the determinant in less time. One more thing is that matrix of $T$ with respect to usual basis is an Orthogonal matrix. Please give some suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The map performs a permutation of the canonical basis. Its determinant is the signature of this permutation. I get $\det T= +1$.

More detailed: Let $e_i$ be the 2 by 3 matrix where $x_i=1$ and the others zero (in the matrix on the left hand side in your definition). Sort of a 'canonical' basis when you think of the matrix as a vector with 6 components. Then
$ T : e_1\mapsto e_3, e_2 \mapsto e_6$, etc... Thus $T e_j = \sum_i e_i t_{ij}$ where $t_{ \sigma(j) j}=1$ (all others zero) with $\sigma$ being the permutation taking $(1,2,...)$ to $(3,6,...)$. Then $\det T = \det t = {\rm sign} \sigma = +1$.

Comment: But my simple calculation det comes as -1....

Comment: where is mistake?

Comment: Justed checked it by writing down the matrix. Still got $+1$

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? I'm not getting it? What specifically can be the canonical basis $B$ and its image under the transformation?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh can you tell something about canonical basis and relation with determinant for more clear

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Lm-Determinant.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would start by decomposing the permutation into disjoint cycles. It is easy to find out the sign from the decomposition. In this case, the decomposition gives one cycle of length 5 and one trivial cycle ($x_5$ doesn't move). A cycle of odd length is even, so it seems like my method gives 1 as the answer...